# Issue in sql server 2005 installing

Tags: sql-server-2005, installation

I tried to install sql server 2005.After the installation  i want to  open sql server 2005.So i just click stat -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2005  but only sub menu(Configuration Tools) is there which is highlighted in below figure.So I can't open the sql server 2005.

[image: Sql]

the above screen sort is taken from another system.

[image: i have]

the above screen sort is taken from my ssytem.

Comment: What are you looking for, exactly? SQL Server Management Studio is what you use to build your databases, and SQL Server Configuration Manager will let you decide how your SQL Server instance(s) are accessed and which services are online.

Comment: yes,I am looking for SQL Server Management Studio to build database.Please help me Cory.

Comment: It's on the bottom of the middle menu in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select `Sql Server Management Studio` from the menu it is last there in the menu in first selection

[image]

Comment: Sql Server Management Studio in not available there. Only Configuration Tools is available. that screen sort is taken from the another system.

Comment: not in second menu check the first one, there is it the last one

Comment: I have only one main menu (Microsoft SQL Server 2005) and One sub menu (Configuration Tools).Don't confuse with above figure. That one is taken from another system for your reference.

Comment: @ChandruA: Then you probably installed *only* the Tools. You might have to repair your installation and select everything for installation, or uninstall everything and try again.

Comment: I tried many time like  what you said above. But still i getting the same.Pleas see my post i added on figure what i have.

Comment: did you installed 2005 server from visual studio?

Comment: IIRC, doens't SQL Server 2005 come on two discs? One with the SQL Server and one with the Tools?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at  [this](http://egranthalaya.nic.in/How_to_Install_and_setup_SQL_Server_2005_Manually.pdf) link.It will help you well.